# Add Toxi library to Processing

Tags: opengl, installation, processing

I'm making a visualization with processing and opengl. I saw an example on this site: http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/just-landed-processing-twitter-metacarta-hidden-data.

Now, I want to use toxi for my visualization. I understand that it's a library. But I don't know how to "set it up." How can I download it (even this is confusing) and how can I add it to make processing work?

(Right now, I get an error saying toxi is not added.)

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

1) Download the latest toxiclibs zipfile from https://bitbucket.org/postspectacular/toxiclibs/downloads/

2) Unzip the file to the /libraries subdirectory of the processing directory

3) Start Processing and the library examples can be found under menu Sketchbook > Libraries > Toxiclibs

Comment: How do I make it run on Raspberrypi.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352280/processing-toxiclips-library-for-raspberrypi

Answer (score 5):

1. Open Processing.
2. Go to File->Preferences.
3. Notice the value of the field labeled "Sketchbook location:".
4. Open this path in a file browser.
5. Inside that folder should be another folder called "libraries". Extract the toxiclib library and copy it into this location.
6. Restart Processing, open the the *.pde sketch and click run.

This worked for me, but it took me a little while to realize that the "libraries" folder was in my "sketchbook"...which none of the other answers mentioned.

e.g. After copying in toxiclib, my path looks like:

```
/home/myusername/sketchbook/libraries/toxiclibs-complete-0020
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Cerin did not work for me. Processing expects a library  structure as described [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/How-to-Install-a-Contributed-Library). In short, every library folder in /sketchbookLocation/libraries has to have some of the folder names: src, examples, library, reference.

Step 5 of @Cerin has to be adjusted a bit. You have to extract the **content** of the toxiclib library zip into the libraries folder.

e.g. After copying in it toxiclib, my path looks like:

```
/home/myusername/sketchbook/libraries/toxiclibscore
```

..and of course all the other folders that are in toxiclibs-complete-0021 are also in the libraries folder.

Ps. most recent version of toxiclib is on [github](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/How-to-Install-a-Contributed-Library).