# Toxi and Processing?

Tags: opengl, installation, processing

I'm trying to add Toxi libraries to Processing. (I want to use processing, opengl, and toxi - together.)

But it's confusing. There's no indication of where to download it (on the download site itself) and I don't know how I'll set it up once I do download it?

**Could you kindly provide a short tutorial of how to do this?**

Thanks soo much guys.

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/4093706/264476 ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Download the latest toxiclibs zipfile from http://hg.postspectacular.com/toxiclibs/downloads/

2) Unzip the file to the /libraries subdirectory of the processing directory

3) Start Processing and the library examples can be found under menu Sketchbook > Libraries > Toxiclibs